# AS3 - Error #1009 when adding an FLVPlayback via "Import Video" into another scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flvplayback

In Flash CS4, if I create a new AS3 file and use File > Import > Import Video to bring in an mp4 video it works great.  However, if I create a new scene and import the video into that, I instantly get this error at runtime:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/__setProp___id0__Scene2_Layer1_0()
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Is this normal behaviour?  I don't get this error using AS2.  How can I add the FLVPlayback object to a different scene in AS3 without explosions?

Answer (score 0):

Never EVER, EVER, ever, EvEr, eVER use scenes, they are inherently evil and will make your life miserable.
I'm sorry, but that's the best answer I've got.